# Best way to make a multidimensional array odd-dimensioned in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax, multidimensional-array, dimensions

I wrote the following function to make a 2-D array object odd-dimensioned by adding a row or column as needed (where sizeX, sizeY, get, set, and resize are self-explanatory grid2D member functions).

```
void makeOdd(grid2D<double> *pSrc)
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Make one or both dimensions of input array odd (via row/column copy).
{

    // Variable declarations
    grid2D<double> pTmp = *pSrc;                                // Scratch local source variable
    int simax, sjmax;                                               // Source dimensions

    // Get source dimensions
    sjmax = pSrc->sizeY();
    simax = pSrc->sizeX();

    // Check if source is already odd-dimensioned
    if (sjmax%2 && simax%2) return;

    // Extend row/column of source if necessary
    if (sjmax%2 && !(simax%2))                                      // Odd rows, even columns
    {
        pSrc->resize(simax+1,sjmax);                                // Resize source with extra column
        for(int i=0; i<simax+1; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<sjmax; j++)
            {
                if(i==simax)
                    pSrc->set(i,j,pTmp.get(simax-1,j));             // Copy last column
                else
                    pSrc->set(i,j,pTmp.get(i,j));
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    else if (!(sjmax%2) && simax%2)                                 // Even rows, odd columns
    {
        pSrc->resize(simax,sjmax+1);                                // Resize source with extra row
        for(int i=0; i<simax; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<sjmax+1; j++)
            {
                if(i==simax)
                    pSrc->set(i,j,pTmp.get(i,sjmax-1));             // Copy last row
                else
                    pSrc->set(i,j,pTmp.get(i,j));
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    else                                                            // Even rows, even columns
    {
        pSrc->resize(simax+1,sjmax+1);                              // Resize source with extra row and column
        for(int i=0; i<simax+1; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<sjmax+1; j++)
            {
                if(i==simax && j==sjmax)
                {
                    pSrc->set(i,j,pTmp.get(simax-1,sjmax-1));       // Copy last column and row
                }
                else if(i==simax && j<sjmax)
                {
                    pSrc->set(i,j,pTmp.get(simax-1,j));             // Copy last column
                }
                else if(i<simax && j==sjmax)
                {
                    pSrc->set(i,j,pTmp.get(i,sjmax-1));             // Copy last row
                }
                else
                {
                    pSrc->set(i,j,pTmp.get(i,j));
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    }

}
```

My question: is there a cleaner/more efficient way of doing this?

Many thanks...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: For example, if I have a double array X with dimension 10x10, I want to make X have dimension 11x11 by copying the last row and column to make the new dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier to check the number of rows first, and extend it by 1 if needed. Then, check the number of columns, and extend each of them by 1 if needed.

Assuming your `grid2d` is a wrapper around a `vector<vector<T> >`, you can pass a value to `resize` that it will use to fill the newly created space, so when you add a row, you can just pass current last row to get it copied into the new last row.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is IMO quite convoluted for this problem... I would do instead

```
void makeOdd(grid2D<double> *pSrc)
{
    int ny = pSrc->sizeY();
    int nx = pSrc->sizeX();
    int oddnx = nx + (nx % 2 == 0);
    int oddny = ny + (ny % 2 == 0);
    if (nx != oddnx || ny != oddny)
    {
        pSrc->resize(oddnx, oddny);
        if (nx != oddnx)
            for (int y=0; y<ny; y++)
                pSrc->set(nx, y, pSrc->get(nx-1, y));
        if (ny != oddny)
            for (int x=0; x<oddnx; x++)
                pSrc->set(x, ny, pSrc->get(x, ny-1));
    }
}
```

Of course depending on `grid2D` this could possibly be even simpler if knowing the internal structure of the object instead of using the public resize/get/set interface (e.g. by making `makeOdd` a method).

By the way in your original code you are making a copy `pTmp` of a pointer (not of the original object); and that's also pointless.

Comment: Hi 6502, Many thanks for the clean and concise code! As to your second point, I defined the "=" operator inside grid2D to memcpy the rhs into a new T (double here) container so the operation isn't pointless.

Comment: Sorry I misread your code and thought you were just making a copy of the pointer (and of course you cannot overload pointer assignment). If the resize operation is however designed to preserve current content (as IMO it should) then there is no need to make a copy: you can just resize and copy elements from second-last column/row to last one.

Comment: Hello 6502, Thanks again for responding. In my "resize" grid2D member function, I delete the <double> container and allocate a new <double> container of the new specified size. How do you suggest this be done to preserve the original content?

Comment: Whoops. I thought that resize was content-preserving (as it is for standard containers). If your implementation instead just wipes out the whole content then at least you should change the name to something like `recreate` or `zap`. How to write an efficient content-preserving resize operation (IMO very useful in general) of course depends on what is the internal representation: is it a single `std::vector<T>` with computed index or an `std::vector<std::vector<T> >`? is it a sparse array `std::map<std::pair<int, int>, double>`?

Comment: The container grid2D is simple: int grid_size_x, int grid_size_y, int grid_size, and T* grid (where T is usually <double>). The data that is being stored (some remote sensing data) can be anything from all-zero to completely full with data depending on conditions. The fastest possible access to the data is a requirement. Do you suggest vectors for this?